# Azure Functions - NodeJS - Hot Reload not working

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I can't find where I enable hot-reload for my NodeJS Azure Function app. Does it have? If so, where can I enable it? I can't find anything here or on Google about NodeJS, only .Net Core.

I'm using the following:

- Typescript
- Node v18
- Core Tools Version: 4.0.5390 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
- Function Runtime Version: 4.25.3.21264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I wasn't running the **"tsc -w"** simultaneously with the "func start". It should work out-of-the-box with no need for any workaround.

If your **local.settings.json** file contains **"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1"**, just remove it and just have **"func start"** and **"tsc -w"** running simultaneously in 2 terminals.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with `Core Tools Version: 4.0.5390`:

***To resolve this, I found two workarounds:***

**Workaround 1:**

Install ***concurrently*** using the command `npm install concurrently`:

[image]

Use `"start": "concurrently \"tsc -w\"  \"func start --typescript\"",` in package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"func start --typescript\"",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0-alpha.9",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Before Changing code:**

[image]

***Response:***

[image]

**After changing the code, compilation restarts:**

[image]

***Response:***

[image]

**Workaround 2:**

- Downgrade my `function core tools version` to `4.0.5095` and it worked.

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.5095 --unsafe-perm true
```

[image]

- Install ***nodemon*** using command `npm install nodemon`.

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/src/functions/*.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prestart": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "start": "nodemon --exec \"func start\"",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0-alpha.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "azure-functions-core-tools": "^4.x",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon":"3.0.1"
  }
}
```

**Before changing the code:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

***Changed code in `httptrigger.ts` class.***

- I could see it *restarted the execution* and the *updated content* as the *localhost response.*

[image]

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[GitHub1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3239)

[GitHub2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/9185)

Comment: When I save a file with changes, it shows that the server restarted on the terminal, but when I make a request using Postman, it still returns the old object as if no change was made. I tried both approaches.

Comment: @SPT It didn't actually help. I tried both and they didn't work. I just found out the issue and I posted the answer.